# In SQL, how can i segment users by number of items they have? (redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm not a SQL expert so apologies if this is actually really simple.

I have a table that lists users and the different questionnaires they have taken. Users can take questionnaires in any order and take as many as they like. There are a total of 7 available and I want to get a view of how many have taken 1 out of 7, 2 of 7, 3 of 7 etc etc

So a really rough example is the table might look like this:

[image: Screenshot of table]

And I want a query that will show me:

```
count Users with 1 Q: 1
count Users with 2 Q: 2
count Users with 3 Q: 0
count Users with 4 Q: 0
count Users with 5 Q: 1
count Users with 6 Q: 0
count Users with 7 Q: 0
```

Comment: You are missing the `userid` on rows.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Hence, there is no obvious way to assign the user id on the missing rows.  And, your question be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two levels of aggregation:

```
select cnt_questionnaires, count(*) cnt_users
from (
    select count(*) cnt_questionnaires from mytable group by userID
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t ;
create table #t (userid INT, q nvarchar(32));
insert into #t 
values 
    (1,'Q1'),
    (1,'Q3'),
    (2,'Q2'),
    (3,'Q1'),
    (3,'Q2'),
    (3,'Q3'),
    (3,'Q4'),
    (3,'Q5'),
    (4,'Q2'),
    (4,'Q3')

-- select * from #t
SELECT 
    v.qCount,
    Count(c.userid) uCount
FROM 
    (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)) v(qCount)
    LEFT JOIN (
                select 
                    userid, count(q) qCount
                from 
                    #t
                group by userid
            ) c ON c.qCount = v.qCount
GROUP BY
    v.qCount
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `user_id` on each row, the challenge is getting the zero values.  Redshift is not very flexible when it comes to creating tables.  Assuming your source data has enough rows, you can use:

```
select n.n, coalesce(u.cnt, 0)
from (select row_number() over () as n
      from t
      limit 7
     ) n left join
     (select user_id, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by user_id
     ) u
     on n.n = u.cnt;
```